# Unable to install OOB SL5 programmatically

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-5.0, out-of-browser

I'm trying to install a brand new Silverlight 5 Application using sllauncher.exe.  When I do this with an older SL4 application, this works fine, however, something about this new SL5 application is different and causing the sllauncher to fail silently.  It does generate a folder in the AppData folder, but it is empty.  Any ideas what might be causing this?  Any way to see the errors that sllauncher is throwing?  Any and all ideas are welcome! (for the method of invoking the sllauncher, I was just following this post: http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2010/03/25/using-sllauncher-for-silent-install-silverlight-application.aspx )

Comment: can you specify exactly how you are invoking sllauncher.exe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case this had nothing to do with Silverlight 5, turns out that the issue was due to the Out Of Browser Icons that I had set, being set to Resource and not Content.  For them to show up and for the install using sllauncher.exe to work, the Icon files must be set to Content, otherwise the Out Of Browser will fail silently when using sllauncher.exe and work just fine using the right-click context menu to install it.